# R Shiny observeEvent continues to trigger

Tags: r, shiny

I'm struggling to get an observeEvent process to run only once after it's triggering event - a button click.  This illustrates:

```
require(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  textInput("input_value", '1. input a value. 2. click button. 3. input another value', ''),
  actionButton("execute", 'execute'),
  textOutput('report')
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$execute, {
    output$report = renderText(input$input_value)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser = T))
```

You'll see that after the button has been clicked once, the textOutput becomes responsive to textInput changes rather than button clicks.

I've tried this approach:

```
server = function(input, output, session) {
  o = observeEvent(input$execute, {
    output$report = renderText(input$input_value)
    o$destroy
  })
}
```

No effect. I've also tried employing the `isolate` function with no luck. Grateful for suggestions.

Comment: This is a very interesting question.  I (shiny novice) think your code should work as posted.  I asked a follow up question here:https://community.rstudio.com/t/observeevent-triggered-by-events-in-the-handling-expression-rather-than-just-the-eventexpr-trigger/103192

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably had your `isolate()` call wrapped around `renderText()` instead of `input$input_value`. This should do it for you:

```
require(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  textInput("input_value", '1. input a value. 2. click button. 3. input another value', ''),
  actionButton("execute", 'execute'),
  textOutput('report')
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$execute, {
    output$report = renderText(isolate(input$input_value))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser = T))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alliteratively you can bring the reactive values into an isolated scope of `observeEvent()` as below:

```r
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  textInput("input_value", '1. input a value. 2. click button. 3. input another value', ''),
  actionButton("execute", 'execute'),
  textOutput('report')
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$execute, {

    # bringing reactive values into an isolated scope
    inp_val <- input$input_value

    output$report <- renderText(inp_val)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser = T))
```